# How to deal with OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '.DS_Store'?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, shutil

I want to copy some pictures from on directory to another directory, and here is my code:

```
import os.path
import shutil

def copyFile(sourceDir,targetDir):
    for files in os.listdir(sourceDir):
        sourceFile=os.path.join(sourceDir,files)
        if os.path.isfile(sourceFile) and sourceFile.find('.jpg')>0:
            shutil.copy(sourceFile,targetDir) 

for i in os.listdir('/Users/liuchong/Desktop/LFW/new'):

    copyFile(i,'/Users/liuchong/Desktop/LFW/lfw')
```

But when I run it ,the terminal tells me that`OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '.DS_Store'` 
I know 'DS_dstore' is a hidden file in Mac, but how can I solve this bug?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic seems badly broken. You iterate through all the files in the directory, passing each one to `copyFile`. But *inside* that function, you again try to iterate through each file in the "directory" passed to the function: except that you're not passing only directories to the function, you're passing each file found in the original directory.

It's not clear what you are trying to do, but I think you need to remove one of those calls to `listdir` and the associated loop.

Comment: I have many folders inside the directory '/Users/liuchong/Desktop/LFW/lfw', and I want to move files in these folders to one directory.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth to mention what is the general meaning of the "Not a directory" error (Errno 20). It means that you are trying to operate with a path which sub-path is a real file and not a directory. That is it is a malformed, incorrect path.

Example: file.txt/test.txt where file.txt is an existing true file (not a directory).

Python will return this error for every I/O operation with such a file:

```
$ python -c 'import os; os.path.getsize("file.txt/test.txt");'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 57, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'file.txt/test.txt'
```

The OS will also return this error:

```
$ stat file.txt/test.txt
stat: cannot stat 'file.txt/test.txt': Not a directory
```

Every time you have this error it means that you concatenate file+file somewhere in your program.

This error is Unix OS specific. On Windows you should get "File not found" for such malformed path.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `os.listdir('/Users/liuchong/Desktop/LFW/lfw')`, it returns both directories and files. You have to check the entry for directory before passing it as an argument.

```
def copyFile(sourceDir,targetDir):
    for files in os.listdir(sourceDir):
        sourceFile=os.path.join(sourceDir,files)
        if os.path.isfile(sourceFile) and sourceFile.find('.jpg')>0:
            shutil.copy(sourceFile,targetDir)

for i in os.listdir('/Users/liuchong/Desktop/LFW/lfw'):
     if os.path.isdir(i):
         i = os.path.join( '/Users/liuchong/Desktop/LFW/lfw', i)
         copyFile(i,'/Users/liuchong/Desktop/LFW/lfw')
```

Comment: Thank you, I add this line 'if os.path.isdir(i)' but the code does not run. Then I print the type of 'i', the output is 'str'....

Comment: You have to add `i = os.path.join( '/Users/liuchong/Desktop/LFW/lfw', i)` before passing the directory to the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.listdir('/Users/liuchong/Desktop/LFW/lfw')
```

returns a list which contains the names of entries in the directory that is given by the user. List is based on random choices.

To address this issue (I know I am late) here's a `python 3` compatible code:-

```
import time
import os
from shutil import copyfile

def Copyfile(in_path, out_path, quantity = None):

    filelist = os.listdir(in_path)
    counter = 0
    print("Copying to %r directory. Please wait... " % out_path)

    start = time.time()

    for i in range(quantity):
        copyfile(filelist[i], out_path+filelist[i])
        counter+=1
        sys.stdout.write("\rTotal images copied : %r" % counter)
        sys.stdout.flush()   

    end = time.time()
    print("This move operation took %r seconds to run." %(end - start))
```