# Saving results of trace function in python

Tags: python, logging, trace

I'm trying to find out some logging information using 'trace' function provided by python using the following code.

```
tracer = trace.Trace(
ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix],
trace=False,
countfuncs = True,
count=False,
timing = True)
tracer.run('exec(script, variables, variables)')

# make a report, placing output in the current directory
r = tracer.results()
r.write_results(show_missing=True,coverdir='trace_vizier')
```

The trace results are getting printed in the terminal but the file where data is saved is not generated.

Could someone tell me why this is happening?

Note - https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html (Trace function)

Comment: "the file where data is saved is not generated." What file is supposed to be generated? (where should it be, and what should its name be? Why?) Why should it be generated? (What part of the code is supposed to make that happen? How?) Where the code says `coverdir='trace_vizier'`, what effect do you expect that to have? Based on the code comment, it seems as if you tried to modify the example in the documentation. Did you try running it without modification first? Did it work as expected? What changes did you expect when you modified it?

Comment: Based on the documentation - https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html I was expecting the coverage results to be saved. AS per the documentation,  " coverdir specifies the directory into which the coverage result files will be output. ". I tried to run it without the modification but still couldn't find any output directory to be generated. I think it should be generated in the directory that's mentioned in the code at write_results function.

Comment: To be clear: a directory named `coverdir` already exists, and you expect files to be written into it, but they are not?

Comment: Yes. The directory already exists.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that It has something to do with putting in-builts functions as command for the run method from Trace, and with the arguments `countfuncs` and `count` that the Trace constructor receives.
Here is what I did:

From the arguments the Trace constructor receives change `countfuncs` and `count` to `countfuncs = False, count=True`.
Next put exec(script, variables, variables)' inside a function of your own and pass it into the run method.

An example:

```py
def test(x):
    exec(x)

tracer = trace.Trace(
ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix],
trace=False,
countfuncs = False,
count=True,
timing = True)
x = 'print("asdf")'
tracer.run('test(x)')

# make a report, placing output in the current directory
r = tracer.results()
r.write_results(show_missing=True,coverdir='trace_vizier')
```

Comment: Thanks @EduC. I made the cahnges and I'm facing another issue: Not printing coverage data for '/home/nachiket/ ... Thanks. I made the changes as you have specified. I'm facing another error - [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/nachiket/...

Comment: Maybe an incorrect path? Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58435212).